# Bitwise operations on negative numbers in C

Tags: c, bit-shift

What is the effect of the following?

```
unsigned int x = -1; x >>= 2;
```

I'm not quite sure what the x gets set to as it's a negative number and the type is unsigned?

Comment: How about inserting some code that will tell you what value it has?

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that. I just didn't understand the significance of the value it returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unsigned int x = -1;
```

sets `x` to `UINT_MAX` (section 6.3.1.3, point 2)¹. The `int` -1 is converted to `unsigned int` for the initialistaion of `x`. That conversion is done by adding (or subtracting, but not here) `UINT_MAX +1` to the value until it is in the range `0 .. UINT_MAX`, once here.

Thus `x >>= 2;` sets `x` to `UINT_MAX/4`, since bitwise right shift of unsigned integers is thus specified in section 6.5.7, point 5:

> The result of `E1 >> E2` is `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions. If `E1` has an unsigned type or if `E1` has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of E1 / 2<sup>E2</sup>.

¹ "Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type."

Answer (score 1):

The -1 should set an unsigned int to 0xffffffff, the highest number for that type (around 4.8 billion) -- or a lot higher if int has more than 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

It is an unsigned type *initialised* by a signed negative value. The shifting is still performed on an unsigned value.

Comment: That doesn't say what the initialized value will be, nor what the result is after the shifting.

Comment: No, Daniel had already answered that. The whole point is : **there is no signed value present in the whole fragment**. The -1 may appear negative, but it is not. It is *only* an initialiser. It is present in the compiled program only as an unsigned value inside x.